# How to read/write high-resolution (24-bit, 8 channel) .wav files in Java?

Tags: java, audio, wav, libsndfile

I'm trying to write a Java application that manipulates high resolution .wav files. I'm having trouble importing the audio data, i.e. converting the .wav file into an array of doubles.

When I use a standard approach an exception is thrown.

```
AudioFileFormat as = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(new File("orig.wav"));
-->
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: file is not a supported file type
```

Here's the file format info according to soxi:

```
dB$ soxi orig.wav
soxi WARN wav: wave header missing FmtExt chunk
```

Input File     : 'orig.wav'
Channels       : 8
Sample Rate    : 96000
Precision      : 24-bit
Duration       : 00:00:03.16 = 303526 samples ~ 237.13 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 9.71M
Bit Rate       : 24.6M
Sample Encoding: 32-bit Floating Point PCM

Can anyone suggest the simplest method for getting this audio into Java?

I've tried using a few techniques.  As stated above, I've experimented with the Java AudioSystem (on both Mac and Windows).  I've also tried using Andrew Greensted's [WavFile class](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html), but this also fails (WavFileException: Compression Code 3 not supported).  One workaround is to convert the audio to 16 bits using sox (with the -b 16 flag), but this is suboptimal since it increases the noise floor.

Incidentally, I've noticed that the file CAN be read by libsndfile.  Is my best bet to write a jni wrapper around libsndfile, or can you suggest something quicker?

Note that I don't need to play the audio, I just need to analyze it, manipulate it, and then write it out to a new .wav file.

***  UPDATE  ***

I solved this problem by modifying Andrew Greensted's [WavFile class](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html). His original version only read files encoded as integer values ("format code 1"); my files were encoded as floats ("format code 3"), and that's what was causing the problem.

I'll post the modified version of Greensted's code when I get a chance.  In the meantime, if anyone wants it, send me a message.

Comment: Might http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810164/how-can-i-write-wav-file-from-byte-array-in-java/5810662#5810662 help?

Comment: I am interested by the WavFile with support with PCM float :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the wav data in yourself, it's actually not that hard to do.  Just search for the WAV file format information.

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a try.  Thanks. :) I'll post my solution here once I figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Very late reply but others might benefit from this.

A [libsndfile java wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/libsndfile-java/) now exists, which should help with audio read/write/conversion issues like this.  The wrapper (generated by swig) is true to the libsndfile API, so the structure is a little different from typical Java style, but entirely usable.

In your particular case, usage would look something like this:

```
String filePath = "path/to/some/audio_8_channels.wav";

// open the sound file
SF_INFO sndInfo = new SF_INFO();
SWIGTYPE_p_SNDFILE_tag sndFile = libsndfile.sf_open(filePath, libsndfile.SFM_READ, sndInfo);

// create a buffer array large enough to hold all channels (double per channel) of all frames
int arraySize = sndInfo.getFrames() * sndInfo.getChannels();
CArrayDouble darray = new CArrayDouble(arraySize);

// read every frame (includes all channels) into the buffer array
long count = libsndfile.sf_readf_double(sndFile, darray.cast(), sndInfo.getFrames());

// iterate over the doubles that make up the audio
for (int i=0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    // every 8 doubles is a frame..
    double d = darray.getitem(i);
}
```

The google code project, including a compiled 'usable' version for JDK1.7 on Windows7 exists here:

http://code.google.com/p/libsndfile-java/