# Finding the duration of a wav file from a URL

Tags: python, audio, wav, pre-signed-url

I'm working in python and I have a signed URL to a wav file. I need to find the duration of that file but I can't find any libraries that do this without requiring me to download it. Are there any libraries like this available or has anyone written code to do this? I've tried AugioSegment but it doesn't look like there's a choice to use a URL.

Comment: the WAV codec has a 44 byte header which contains the length of the payload ... this value is not guaranteed to be accurate yet may work ... so do a read which is limited to only retrieving those header bytes then pluck out the proper header attribute

Comment: here is the WAV file  header layout https://stackoverflow.com/a/28137825/147175